# matlab figure taking too long to open

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot, fig

I want to save a plot in .fig extension. I tried many ways but it takes too long to open (in fact it never opens sometimes after infinite wait time). I had to use Ctrl C in the command prompt to stop it.

Here are my commands to print a figure in fig format

```
  saveas(h,[path FolderName FigureName, '.fig'])
```

where h is the handler. I used h at many places in the code file 
(where the variables inputsAxis etc.., are defined basing on the where I need to plot. plot count is set to 10, inputsAxis = [1,2],SignalAxis = [3 4], VoterOutAxis -= 5 )

```
  h(1) = subplot(plotCount,1,inputsAxis);
  h(2) = subplot(plotCount,1,SignalAxis);
  h(7) = subplot(plotCount,1,voterOutAxis);
  h(5) = subplot(plotCount,1,FlagAxis);
  h(6) = subplot(plotCount,1,MarginAxis);
  h(9) = subplot(plotCount,1,flagAxis,'Color',[1 1 0]);
```

Also used

```
   savefig([Path FolderName FigureName '.fig'])
```

I can print in the jpeg file but it is not as good as .fig for the simulation I am running.

I am not sure what I am missing here. It is more useful to me saving the figure in .fig format but when I do I can not open it by double clicking on it or by using openfig(filename) command.

Comment: Wow you waited an infinite amount of time and it didn't open? You must very patient!

Comment: Did you try using `open` rather than `openfig`?

Comment: @David hypothetically yeah, waited for ever. Yes, used open - same result (wouldn't open). Did I mention that the size of these figures is like 12MB?

Comment: 12MB doesn't sound too big. It might be better to just save the data used to make the plot, and then make a function with the code to create it from that data. Then instead of saving/loading just recreate each time you need it. Without more information it is hard to say more.

Comment: How about saving as .eps, or to increase the resolution of your jpg/png file? One possibility why your .fig might be slow is the amount of data that it needs to write (or interpret, when opening).

Comment: @David: I have lots of data and the script iterates over it. It might be too complicated to save the data to plot in a function and call it every time I want to see the plot. By the way I tried reducing the resolution and opening and still it is not opening. I want it to be in fig format to perform analysis on the plot.

Comment: @barceloco: perhaps, because I am having around 10 subplots in each fig. Simulation time is around 100 seconds on average. .fig is more useful in analyzing that data. That is the reason I am not saving in other formats.

Comment: @user2927392 :  In this case, I would suggest trying to have one individual .fig file for each sub-plot. It smells a bit like matlab doesn't like to dig through all these sub-plots. Just guessing...

Comment: @user2927392 : also, if you want to data analysis within matlab, **consider not saving your data as a .fig file but as a .mat file**, i.e. to just store the data, not the plot of the data; this is what I typically do and it's quite fast. Good luck!

Comment: @barceloco: can I load figure from the .mat file at any point of time later?

Comment: @user2927392 : yes, you can. Check out http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html?refresh=true for a detailed explanation of the `save` and `load` commands in Matlab. You can even decide which variables you wish to save. Cheers

Comment: @user2927392 : did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Following our discussion in your comments section, my suggestion is to save your variables into a `.mat` file, which is very fast.

For example, if you want to save specific variable `a`, simply enter

```
a=3;
save('variables.mat', 'a');
clear all;
load('variables.mat');
```

Alternatively, if you simply want to save all variables into a `.mat` file, enter

```
save('allMyVariables.mat');
clear all;
load('allMyVariables.mat');
```

Please note that I wrote `clear all` to indicate that you may overwrite variables between `save` and `load`, or that you may even restart Matlab completely.

Check out http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html?refresh=true for a detailed explanation.

Cheers